# Open colorbox iframe on page load automatically

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I figured this out and thought i'd post it, cuz i dint find an answer here.  However, if you see anything wrong with this, please lmk.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$.colorbox({open:true,href:"http://siteyouwantopened.com",iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});`
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Doug. This is not how we ask questions here. This looks more like an answer than a question. We answer questions as they arise, not pre-emptively.

Comment: The above information can easily be found in the ColorBox docs @ http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox